# Elementary proof that, in a topos, every epimorphism is regular?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Mac Lane and Moerdijk have a neat proof on p. 197 that, in a topos $\mathcal{E}$, every epimorphism $f \colon C \to B$ is a coequalizer. But this depends on the assumption that the slice category $\mathcal{E}/B$ is itself a topos.

The Elephant gets there sooner, and has a proof by p. 38 that, in a (pre)topos, every epimorphism is a coequalizer. But again this depends on some moderately fancy earlier moves.

So here's the question: is there a significantly more elementary proof of the result which requires less scene-setting, requires only relatively small steps on from the definition of an elementary topos?

I had the impression that I'd somewhere, sometime, seen a simpler proof (indeed, maybe even here on math.se??). But I can't locate one: so maybe I'm just having a senior moment!

Comment: Perhaps it follows from the computation of colimits via the powerobject equivalence functor?

Comment: The two arguments are actually the same.
a) If a category has a subobject classifier, then all monomorphisms are strong.
b) If all monomorphisms are strong, then all epimorphisms are strong.
c) If coequalizers of kernel pairs exist and have pullbacks that are epimorphisms, then every morphism factors as a regular epimorphism followed by a monomorphism.
d) A strong monomorphism factors as a regular epimorphism followed by a monomorphism if and only if it is regular.

The two hypotheses for c) hold in a topos by monadicity of contravariant power object functor and local cartesian closure.

Comment: This question then amounts to whether one can show strong epis are regular in a topos without showing that coequalizers of kernel pairs both exist and have pullbacks that are epimorphisms.

Comment: Maybe there would be a way to show more or less directly that if you take the pullback of the diagonal map $B \to B \times B$ and $f \times f : C \times C \to B \times B$, then $f$ is the coequalizer of the two projections from the pullback to $C$?

Comment: I think I have an argument which is fairly elementary, except that it uses the fact that any morphism in a topos which is a monomorphism and an epimorphism is an isomorphism.  Would that count as elementary enough?  (I don't remember exactly how that latter fact is bootstrapped in a topos.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler That would surely count :) Being balanced is an almost immediate consequence of having a subobect classifier.

Answer (score 3):

We will show that in fact, any epimorphism $f : C \to B$ in a topos is effective, i.e. $f$ is the coequalizer of the two projections $C \times_B C \to C$.  Thus, suppose we have a morphism $g : C \to X$ such that $g \circ \pi_1 = g \circ \pi_2$.  Then set $I$ to be the image of $(f, g) : C \to B \times X$.  We claim that the first projection $I \to B$ is an isomorphism; then the required morphism $B \to X$ will be the composition of the inverse of $I \to B$ with the second projection $I \to X$ (and the uniqueness of the map $B \to X$ will be an immediate consequence of $f$ being an epimorphism).

To see this, first note that the projection $\bar \pi_1 : I \to B$ is certainly an epimorphism, since $\pi_1 \circ (f, g) = f$ is an epimorphism.  Therefore, we reduce to showing that the projection $I \to B$ is a monomorphism.  To see this, suppose we have two morphisms $i, j : U \to I$ such that $\bar\pi_1 \circ i = \bar\pi_1 \circ j$.  Then there exists an epimorphism $V \to U$ and two morphisms $\bar i, \bar j : V \to C$ making appropriate commutative diagrams with $i,j$ respectively.  But then the fact that $\bar \pi_1 \circ i = \bar \pi_1 \circ j$ implies that $(\bar i, \bar j)$ induces a morphism $V \to C \times_B C$.  Therefore, the assumption $g \circ \pi_1 = g \circ \pi_2$ implies that $g \circ \bar i = g \circ \bar j$; and from $V \to U$ being an epimorphism, we get that $\bar \pi_2 \circ i = \bar \pi_2 \circ j$ also.  From here, we can conclude that in fact $i = j$.

---

In case there is any difficulty in filling in the details of this argument, let me just comment that this is a categorization of this completely elementary argument for the case of $\mathsf{Set}$: first, with the given setup, the assumption $g \circ \pi_1 = g \circ \pi_2$ amounts to the requirement that whenever $c_1, c_2 : C$ are such that $f(c_1) = f(c_2)$, then $g(c_1) = g(c_2)$.  Now, $I = \{ (b, x) : B \times X \mid \exists c : C, f(c) = b \land g(c) = x \}$.  It is immediate from $f$ being surjective that every $b : B$ occurs as a first coordinate of an element of $I$.  On the other hand, if $(b, x_1), (b, x_2) \in I$, then there exist $c_1, c_2 : C$ such that $f(c_1) = f(c_2) = b$, $g(c_1) = x_1$, and $g(c_2) = x_2$.  But then the assumption $g \circ \pi_1 = g \circ \pi_2$ gives $x_1 = x_2$.  Thus, we have shown that $I$ is the graph of some function $B \to X$.

(Also, let me observe that the dependencies of the topos case argument are: that a topos is balanced, i.e. every morphism which is a monomorphism and an epimorphism is an isomorphism; the existence of images, i.e. epi-mono factorizations; and that in a topos, epimorphisms are stable under pullbacks.)

Comment: Thanks!! I'm off to draw some diagrams, but this looks very helpful. :) Though I suppose we could wonder whether  background assumption (3) -- that in a topos epimorphisms are stable under pullbacks --  counts as "elementary" (roughly on a par with the other two assumptions).  I note e.g. that in the old answer I link here (which you commented on!) the suggested more elementary proof for (3) depends on the premiss that in a topos every epimorphism is regular! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129508/do-pull-backs-preserve-epi-morphisms-in-a-topos/4129649#4129649

Comment: Hmm, maybe it might be helpful to use the construction of the image of $h : X \to Y$ as the (internal) intersection of all $S : P(Y)$ such that $h^{-1}(S) = \top_X$.  Then you could get around the other proof I gave by setting $S$ to be the set of $(b, x) : B \times X$ such that $\forall c : C, f(c) = b \rightarrow g(c) = x$ (though that's perhaps starting to get into the territory of things that are easier to specify using the internal language machinery than in an elementary manner).

Comment: Otherwise, I think I saw a proof that was something along the lines of: prove that in a topos, $h : X \to Y$ is an epimorphism if and only if $\operatorname{id}_Y, \operatorname{id}_Y : Y \to Y$ give a pushout of $h$ and $h$.  Then since pullbacks trivially preserve pushouts and isomorphisms, the result would follow immediately.  I don't remember if that proof has the same potential circularity issue, though.

Comment: Very nice. Distilled, the argument says that if every span in a category has a factorization as an epi in a pullback-stable class followed by a relation, then every morphism has a factorization as an epi in the pullback-stable class followed by the mono, that such factorizations of a given morphism are a cofiltered pe-order with initial elements the factorizations whose pullback-stable epis are effective.

Comment: Note that the existence of image factorizations would follow from the existence of weak cokernel pairs. Still unclear how to get that without monaditiy of power functor.

Comment: I think the alternate construction of image I outlined in an earlier comment, namely the internal intersection of all $S : P(Y)$ such that $h^{-1}(S) = \top_X$, should work fine without needing modadicity of power functor.